# Error : "The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly." while using WebClient.DownloadFIleAsync

Tags: c#, github, webclient

I am using C# in my code, Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

I want to download release file asyncronously from private Github repository, and already have the download Uri :

> https://github.com/<'Github
>   user'>/<'repo'>/releases/download/1.0.7.4/<'7zip file to download'>

This error always come up if I use the Uri above:

*The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.*

**Oddly, if I try another Uri from my repo, it successfully downloaded.**

> This is my another Uri : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<'Github
>   user'>/<'repo'>/master/<'7zip file to download'>

Here is my code

```
// Set up WebClient to download file
        webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
        webClient.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        //webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        //webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, string.Format("token {0}", applicationInfo.TokenAuthorization));
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadFileCompleted);

        // Download file
        try
        { webClient.DownloadFileAsync(updateInfo.Uri, this.temp7zFile); }
        catch { this.DialogResult = DialogResult.No; this.Close(); }
```

I have tried to add (right now it remarked)

> webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

or

> webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization,
>   string.Format("token {0}", applicationInfo.TokenAuthorization));

the result always the same = *The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.*

I really don't know what's wrong and I have been struggling for 3 days..

**note:**

*- both of those Uri is correct, if I run it in firefox browser, it automatically download.*

*- applicationInfo.TokenAuthorization : is the token for Github authorization.*

*- updateInfo.Uri : is Uri address*

*- this.temp7zFile : is destination downloaded file*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the gap. Wrong Url and must handle redirect!

Based on [Github Release](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release-asset), to download binary or release file from private repo, use the Url of assets.

Github will send redirect download Url from http://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com with some parameters in it.

You just use that Url in WebClient.DownloadFileAsync , without header or authorization etc, and the file will arrive on your local drive happyly ever after..

Its all because of private repo.

Hope this usefull for you all..